# Under what conditions does a Windows Azure website change IP addresses?

Tags: ip, azure

I am about to launch a website in Windows Azure and I need to poke some holes in our network firewall in order to accommodate  certain services like SMTP. I've found an MSDN page which seems relevant that describes [in-place updates](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2011/10/19/announcing-improved-in-place-updates.aspx) but I'm having trouble making sense out of it.

What are the circumstances that trigger a change of IP address for a site in Windows Azure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you delete, then redeploy, a hosted service, you'll get a new IP address. The post you referred to talks about ways you can update your running hosted service, without the need for delete+redeploy (which equates to "without changing IP address" as well).

The one case I'm aware of, where you *do* need to delete+redeploy, is the case of *reducing* local storage.

Comment: I've deleted and redeployed when the deployment failed at start up and was stuck in a infinite loop of startup-fail-recycle. Not sure if I *needed* to delete+redeploy in that scenario though. Thanks.